# latex beamer arrow color

Tags: beamer, itemize

How can I change the arrow color in beamer? by default they're blue triangles

I tried

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle, red]
```

and

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]{\color{red}}
```

I want to make this for all slides in my presentation.  (Note to self: 20 years coding experience and nothing in Latex is where I expect it to be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colour of the itemize items can be changed by setting the colour of the same name:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=red}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}

\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```